# Showing collection of values in a crystal sub report

Tags: collections, crystal-reports, reporting, subreport

I have a C# class that contains a collection property. I am showing this data in a sub report. In design editor I find that the collection property is not seen in the list of available columns. How can I show these values then ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by using a string property and made a comma separated list of values present in the collection and assigning it to the string property.